# Problem getting friends events via FB connect

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm trying to get the user's events and his friends events by the Graph API.

first, is there any other option getting all the friends events except sending new query for every one of them? (even if it exists in other protocols)

for( NSDictionary *friend in friends )  {

```
        NSLog(@"sending events for %@", [friend objectForKey:@"id"]);
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:
         [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/events&since=today&until=tomorrow&limit=10", [friend objectForKey:@"id"]]
                           andDelegate:self];
    }
```

second, can I get ALL the user's events and not just what he has marked attendance status for?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to take [Extended Permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) of user_events and friends events. As for as your second part of question is concerened you can query to [event_member](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member/) table to get status. hope it will work

Comment: Thanks but I've meant that for a certain user I want to get all his friends events. For now I'm sending request for every one of them and that's really slow. Is there any option getting the information in one request or something more efficient but this approach?

Comment: How you are sending request? Can you please edit your question and provide your code?

Comment: yeap, friends array contain all the friends from previous query it makes and then:         `for( NSDictionary *friend in friends ) {
   
   NSLog(@"sending events for %@", [friend objectForKey:@"id"]);
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/events&since=today&until=tomorrow&limit=10", [friend objectForKey:@"id"]]
          andDelegate:self];
  }`